# Output giving me a NaN ,why? [ complete ]

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, nan

I'm trying to pass an arraylist through a method, and I wanted to display it. This is my code

```
        public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr) {
        
        ArrayList<Float> ssGrades = new ArrayList<Float>();
    
        float ss = 0, data = 0, sum = 0, avg = 0;
        
        for (int i= 0; i < ssGrade.size(); i++)
        {
            data = ssGrades.get(intIndex);
            sum += fltData;
            System.out.println(fdata);
        }  
        
        avg = sum/ ssGrades.size();
        System.out.println("\nAverage is " + avg+ ".");     
    }
}
```

The problem is my output is giving a NaN instead of the computation of average scores, why so? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the exact output (including stack trace) you get?

Comment: it just give me an output of: Average is NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr)` method instead of using the `arr` array parameter you defined an empty new array and iterate through it which you have to change it as below to work correctly, secondly I add cast to cast value of `fltAverage = (float)fltSum / arr.size();` to float so be precise.

```
public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr) {
        float fltGrade, fltData, fltSum, fltAverage;
        fltGrade = fltData = fltSum = fltAverage = 0;
        
        System.out.println("\n\nGenerating grade listing");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < arr.size(); intIndex++) {
            fltData = arr.get(intIndex);
            fltSum += fltData;
            System.out.println(fltData);
        }

        fltAverage = (float)fltSum / arr.size();
        System.out.println("\nAverage is " + fltAverage + ".");
    }
```

the complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner objDataEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Float> objGrades = new ArrayList<Float>();
        float fltGrade, fltData, fltSum, fltAverage;
        fltGrade = fltData = fltSum = fltAverage = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a grade, -1 to exit..");
        while (fltGrade >= 0) {
            System.out.print("Grade: ");
            fltGrade = objDataEntry.nextFloat();

            if (fltGrade >= 0) {
                objGrades.add(fltGrade);
            }
        }
        dispArrayList(objGrades);
    }

    public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr) {
        float fltGrade, fltData, fltSum, fltAverage;
        fltGrade = fltData = fltSum = fltAverage = 0;
        
        System.out.println("\n\nGenerating grade listing");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < arr.size(); intIndex++) {
            fltData = arr.get(intIndex);
            fltSum += fltData;
            System.out.println(fltData);
        }

        fltAverage = (float)fltSum / arr.size();
        System.out.println("\nAverage is " + fltAverage + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Scanner#nextFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat--) can return `NaN` if the read value isn't a valid floating point number.

Once there's a single `NaN` value in your list, the sum of all values will be `NaN` too.

Additionally, you don't loop over the `arr` list in your `dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr)` method but over the empty `ArrayList<Float> objGrades`, so that the following line will evaluate to `NaN` because of the division by zero:

```
fltAverage = fltSum / objGrades.size();
// fltAverage = 0.0f / 0.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the ArrayList passing to dispArrayList method.

delete this line `ArrayList objGrades = new ArrayList();` inside dispArrayList method

and change this `public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList arr)` into `public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList objGrades)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you did not use the parameter passed in method dispArrayList(ArrayList arr)
and divide by zero.

Comment: give it a thumb up if u can

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create a new ArrayList in display method 
use the passed array instead `arr` 
also never initialize a bunch of variables like that

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner objDataEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Float> objGrades = new ArrayList<Float>();
    float fltGrade = 0, fltData = 0, fltSum = 0, fltAverage = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter a grade, -1 to exit..");
    while (fltGrade >= 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Grade: ");
        fltGrade = objDataEntry.nextFloat();

        if (fltGrade >= 0)
        {
            objGrades.add(fltGrade);
        }
    }
    dispArrayList(objGrades);
}


public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr) {
    float fltGrade = 0, fltData = 0, fltSum = 0, fltAverage = 0;
    
    System.out.println("\n\nGenerating grade listing");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < arr.size(); intIndex++)
    {
        fltData = arr.get(intIndex);
        fltSum += fltData;
        System.out.println(fltData);
    }

    fltAverage = fltSum / arr.size();
    System.out.println("\nAverage is " + fltAverage + ".");

}
```

Also, you have got a lot useless variables that you don't need

**modified code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner objDataEntry = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Float> objGrades = new ArrayList<Float>();
    float fltGrade = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter a grade, -1 to exit..");
    while (fltGrade >= 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Grade: ");
        fltGrade = objDataEntry.nextFloat();

        if (fltGrade >= 0)
        {
            objGrades.add(fltGrade);
        }
    }
    dispArrayList(objGrades);
}


public static void dispArrayList(ArrayList<Float> arr) {
    float fltSum = 0, fltAverage = 0;

    System.out.println("\n\nGenerating grade listing");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < arr.size(); intIndex++)
    {
        fltSum += arr.get(intIndex);
        System.out.println(arr.get(intIndex));
    }

    fltAverage = fltSum / arr.size();
    System.out.println("\nAverage is " + fltAverage + ".");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `fltSum` and `objGrades.size()` are both 0.

```
ZERO / ZERO = NaN
```

You can refer this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-not-a-number